# convert mp3 audio to aac m4a audio

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, aac, m4a

It may be easy, but I'm new to ffmpeg and struggle with converting an mp3 audio to an aac audio file with .m4a file extension using ffmpeg on the command line (Win10).

input: `Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s`

desired output: `Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s`

The output details are taken from a file that works for my requirements and that was created using Audacity ("Export: M4A (AAC) files (FFmpeg)"). The output file should have .m4a file extension, but I could change that in another step if that's not possible.

I assume that the quality of the output remains (at least almost) the same. If that's not true, please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `ffmpeg -i in -vn out.m4a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert with the best quality and your ffmpeg have libfdk_aac (Fraunhofer AAC encoder) you can use command:

```
ffmpeg -i inFile.mp3 -c:a libfdk_aac outFile.m4a
```

otherwise, you can use the command:

```
ffmpeg -i inFile.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 192k outFile.m4a
```

with bitrate control